# how to make new url in rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have model/controller called notification.

I want to make a new url so that I can access it by:

`/notifications/my_new_url?id=4` and have that page go to view `my_new_url.html.erb`

however, it always keeps going to `show` method:

This is in my `routes.rb`

```
  map.resources :notifications

  map.connect 'notifications/get',
              :controller => 'notifications',
              :action     => 'show'            

  map.connect 'notifications/my_new_url',
              :controller => 'notifications',
              :action     => 'my_new_url'
```

Please assist me...I've been stuck on this for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the URL to a controller and action combination. But your action can render the view. You also need need to map the specialized URLs before URLs with wildcards. So do this:

```
# config/routes.rb
    ...
    map.connect 'notifications/my_new_url',
                :controller => 'notifications',
                :action => 'my_new_url'

    map.resources :notifications
    ...


# app/controllers/notifications_controller.rb
  ...
  def my_new_url
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :my_new_url }
    end
  end
  ...

# app/views/notifications/my_new_url.html.erb
  ...
```

Comment: for the mean time I've added if/else in show method to render different pages

Comment: Put `map.resources :notifications` after all special routes within 'notifications/***'.

Comment: That route should also be defined before the routes `map.resources :notifications` because the first route the url matches will be the one it follows, and that route will also match the show (which is why it keeps going to the show). Also, there should be some syntax to specify a collection, which is a much smarter route. Unfortunately Rails, is going through so many changes right now, and the router in particular has gone through so many changes in the lifetime of Rails, that I am not sure where to point to.

Comment: @samwick - did you reload your server/application after adding the route?